# how to archive the rolling log into a different floder in ent library v4.1

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library, logging-application-block

I want to know what is the simplest way to archive my old logs into a folder but not in the main logging file directory.
what the hell do I mean?

for example: I logging into a file called "Operation_Log.txt" and I every day\10mb the log is "rolled" and a new Operation_Log.txt" is created and the old file become "$CurrentTime_Operation_Log.txt", I want the "rolled" file to be created in a different directory how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to Ent Lib 5.0 - in the logging application block there is a new configuration to enable to the saving on only a number of old logs files

Answer (score 0):

Build an application that can do it and have it reside on the server. Have it run once per day as a scheduled task.
See documentation on the [System.IO.File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) for Reading/Writing the files.
Now.ToString will give you the current time in string format in .Net.

Comment: I know how I can do it that way.
My question was can this be done by changing the configuration on enterprise library logging application block.